# STK MATLAB interface. Trying to access Range Rate data

Tags: matlab, satellite

I'm trying to get the Range Rate data between a satellite and ground site and everything works up until the last line. I've followed the online example but I get the error (below) when running this MATLAB script:

```
stk = stkApp.Personality2;
stkScenario = stk.CurrentScenario;
if isempty(stkScenario)
    error('Please load a scenario');
end

facility = stk.GetObjectFromPath('Facility/RRFac');

satellite = stk.GetObjectFromPath('Satellite/P02S01');
access = satellite.GetAccessToObject(facility);
access.ComputeAccess;

accessDP = access.DataProviders.Item('Access Data').Exec(stkScenario.StartTime,stkScenario.StopTime);
accessStartTimes = accessDP.DataSets.GetDataSetByName('Start Time').GetValues;
accessStopTimes = accessDP.DataSets.GetDataSetByName('Stop Time').GetValues;

accessIntervals = access.ComputedAccessIntervalTimes;

accessDataProvider = access.DataProviders.Item('Access Data');
dataProviderElements = {'Start Time';'Stop Time'};
accessIntervals = access.ComputedAccessIntervalTimes;
for i = 1:1:accessIntervals.Count
    [start, stop]   = accessIntervals.GetInterval(i-1);
    satelliteDP = satellite.DataProviders.Item('DeckAccess Data').Group.Item('Start Time LocalHorizontal Geometry').ExecElements(accessStartTimes{1},accessStopTimes{1},{'Time';'Range Rate'});
    satelliteAlt = satelliteDP.DataSets.GetDataSetByName('Range Rate').GetValues;
end
```

```
Error using Interface.AGI_STK_Objects_12_IAgDrDataSetCollection/GetDataSetByName Invoke Error, Dispatch Exception: The parameter is incorrect.

Error in GenRRreport (line 37)
    satelliteAlt = satelliteDP.DataSets.GetDataSetByName('Range Rate').GetValues
```

Why does it throw this error and how to avoid that?

Comment: Can you please [edit] the post to link to the online example? As the error suggests, there's an incorrect parameter somewhere.

Comment: Yea the error is generated at this line:   satelliteAlt = satelliteDP.DataSets.GetDataSetByName('Range Rate').GetValues;   ... I'm not using the correct access method to get the Range Rate via the data provider...

Comment: Sorry, the scenario is proprietary so I can't post the STK setup... but this will happen with any satellite setup... it's my misuse of the data provider at the very end that's the issue. I must be using it incorrectly, but the documentation isn't helping.